# How to configure authorization in Keycloak to prevent SAML Request Denied Response

Tags: javascript, angular, saml, keycloak

I am very new to Keycloak. I am using Keycloak as an Identity Broker and integrated with ADFS(SAML). I am log-in from Angular web app and posting SAML request to ADFS via Keycloak. I want to deny the user to access the web application for access denied response from ADFS using Keycloak Authorization

I tried to enable Keycloak Authorization and created a policy using below js

**$evaluation.deny();**

I want to deny the user to access web application after getting

```
> <samlp:StatusCode
> Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder"><samlp:StatusCode
> Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:RequestDenied"/></samlp:StatusCode>
>     </samlp:Status>
```

using Keycloak Authorization. But whenever I get "RequestDenied" from ADFS, my angular web application goes into a loop.
However, I am getting ***"status:RequestDenied"*** but actual HTTP status code is 200.

Please, suggest how to configure **Keycloak Authorization** for angular web app resource.

Comment: Finally, I found the way to handle "status:RequestDenied" saml response. For that Customised keycloack-service and added check for this status code and redirect to the Error page.